# How to connect lcd screen to computer?

Tags: display, lcd, tv

I have a Westinghouse LCD TV but it does not work because its some part is not working, the lcd display is ok. I want to use its lcd display as a computer monitor. I wonder if it is possible. Is the lcd tv screen connection to the TV and lcd computer monitor connection to the computer are same?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what the model number of the TV is?

Comment: More info on the PC would be helpful as well. You may need an adapter, especially if you've got a laptop.

Comment: In addition, tell us how are you connecting the computer and the lcd tv, via vga? hdmi?

Comment: Model is TX-42F430S. Its main board is not working (according to the mechanic). It does not power up. All computers (window, linux, mac) uses lcd monitor, so I think type of computer does matter. However, I am planning to use with "Raspberry Pi" running Linux.

Comment: All computers (window, linux, mac) uses lcd monitor, so I think type of computer does not matter.  However, I am planning to use with "Raspberry Pi" running Linux. TV has HTMI as well as VGA ports. Also, "Raspberry Pi" has HTMI port. But my TV does not power up. So, I am thinking to power up the lcd only and connect it to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If the TV and the computer Graphics card both have HDMI, you only need an HDMI cable and you can use it as a computer monitor. It works just fine if they both have a VGA connector as well. On the other hand, if they don't have the same connectors you may just need an external adapter on one of the ends to make it work.